# How can I add multiple transformations to my control?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to scale it and rotate it. But my control only takes inn one transformation as it `.RenderTransform`.

How can I add a ScaleTransform and a Rotatetransform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is taken right from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.transformgroup.aspx)

```
<Page 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" >
  <StackPanel Margin="50">

      <Button 
        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center">Click
        <Button.RenderTransform>

          <!-- TransformGroup enables you to apply multiple transforms. In 
               this example, the button is scaled and rotated. -->
          <TransformGroup>

            <!-- Triple the size (scale) of the button in the Y direction. -->
            <ScaleTransform ScaleY="3" />

            <!-- Rotate the button by 45 degrees. -->
            <RotateTransform Angle="45" />

          </TransformGroup>
        </Button.RenderTransform>
      </Button>

  </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

Comment: It is also possible to use a `CompositeTransform`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.compositetransform(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: @KooKiz +1; Unless individual Transforms are a necessity, CompositeTransform looks rather promising.